# How to avoid problems with “.” in identifier in DSL file [Jenkins]?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dsl

I have such part in DSL file

```
    components{
        bq(type: 'SOAPartition'){
            partitionName 'bq'
        }
        SearchDepositProductBQProvA_v1.0(type:'SCA'){ 
                group  'ru.vtb24.ULBSF.DepositProductCRMReqA' 
                name  'SearchDepositProductBQProvA_v1.0' 
                version '3.0.0.0' 
                classifier 'sca' 
                extension 'jar' 
                artifactBuildFile 'FMW_12/DepositProductCRMReqA/SearchDepositProductBQProvA_v1.0/pom.xml'

                isDefault 'true' 
                partition 'bq' 
                checkTokens 'true' 
        } 
    }
```

and there's an error 'Script1.groovy: 31: unexpected token: 0 @ line 31, column 33.
12:22:13        SearchDepositProductBQProvA_v1.0(type:'SCA'){'.

How can I leave '.' and solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try with quoting the identifier?  (Jenkins DSL is restrictive than groovy.  May or may not work)

Comment: I tried and it works. Thank you

Comment: Good to know. You may answer your question with your new code.  That may help someone else later.

Comment: I think it won't work, since methods or properties cannot start with a number. Error message says unexpected token... Anyway you could try to override the static missing_method and check if the name is '0': http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_static_methodmissing

Comment: put the version as an argument:
SearchDepositProductBQProvA 'v1.0', type:'SCA' {...
}